# SQL Statement not giving correct output

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

I have an database-driven webapp. In my DB I have four tables:

```
User
----
UserID
FirstName
LastName

UserGroup
---------
UserGroupID
UserID
GroupID

Group
-----
GroupID
Name

Adress
------
AdressID
UserID
Street
...
```

With my current SQL statement I get nothing returned. Here is my SQL:

```
select 
    a.UserID, a.FirstName, a.LastName, b.GroupID, b.UserID, 
    c.GroupID, c.Name, d.AdressID, d.UserID, 
from User as a, UserGroup as b, Group as c, Adress as d 
where a.UserID = b.UserID and b.GroupID = c.GroupID 
    and a.UserID = d.UserID and d.AdressID= @id"
```

I supply the variable id with the following statement:

```
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
```

Any idea why I got nothing returned? I also get no error whatsoever. I store the result in `DataTable` which is empty when debugging.

Comment: What kind of database is it?

Comment: If it's (at least) mssql, you shouldn't have a comma before `from`

Comment: Ugh, PLEASE use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  You are lucky you aren't getting millions of rows back due to an inadvertent cross join.

Comment: You really should be using ANSI joins, and not `WHERE` statements to join everything.  Also, since you're doing inner joins, are there any records that actually have an address for the ID specified?

Comment: are you sure you have rows in all the tables that match what you are trying to get?

Comment: _"Any idea why I got nothing returned? I also get no error whatsoever."_ - do you execute the command?

Comment: I use IIS and the database does have an .mdf extension. other sql in this webapp is working so I guess I got the wrong syntax...

Comment: Maybe you're executing your command in a Try/Catch block without warnings! The SELECT contains some sintax errors!

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect when run this query from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) on this database?

Comment: I do not yet know how to use joins correctly so this will have to do

Comment: Sounds like the perfect time to learn

Comment: @CodeCaster of course I run the command, I did debugging on it so it got executed

Comment: You can execute your query in SSMS with static id and see the oupput and let us know whether it works?

Comment: Also: I would recommend using **meaningful** table alias - not just `a, b, c, d` - you'll never know what it what.... use `User as u`, `Group as g`, `UserGroup as ug` and so on - makes it **much easier** (especially for others) to understand your SQL!

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: `.mdf` **is** SQL Server - Access would be `.mdb` ...

Comment: @marc_s - <head slap> -- thank you, it's early :|

Comment: _"of course I run the command, I did debugging on it so it got executed"_ - that does not answer my question, I meant to ask whether you called any `.Execute()` method on it. Show the exact code from initialization to assignment to your datatable.

Comment: @CodeCaster sorry but I thought you were only asking if I run the code. I cant post the logic here as this is for a project for a company where I do my internship at. but I was pretty sure my error was in my syntax so I thought posting it would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have comma before 'from' and also you are better of with using `inner join` than joining like that:

```
select a.UserID, a.FirstName, a.LastName, b.GroupID, b.UserID, c.GroupID, c.Name, d.AdressID, d.UserID
from User as a
inner join UserGroup as b on b.UserId = a.UserId
inner join Group as c on c.GroupID = b.GroupID
inner join Adress as d on a.UserID = d.UserID
where d.AdressID = @id
```

try this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try with an `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT a.UserID, a.FirstName, a.LastName, b.GroupID, b.UserID, c.GroupID, c.Name, d.AdressID, d.UserID
FROM User as a
INNER JOIN UserGroup as b 
ON a.UserID = b.UserID 
INNER JOIN Group as c 
ON b.GroupID = c.GroupID
INNER JOIN Adress as d 
ON a.UserID = d.UserID
WHERE d.AdressID= @id
```